# SQL query to create a view with additional column based on successive row values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table similar to below .

| A Id | B session Id | C customer Type | D ticket status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | vip | Failed |
| First | B | ordinary | Success |
| First | C | ordinary | Success |
| Second | D | ordinary | Success |
| Third | E | vip | Failed |
| Third | F | ordinary | Success |

Now I want to create a view using the above table  where I need to create a new column say Success count in the view along with this table values when the customer type is VIP I need to check the subsequent session id(column B) with Same A Id value to see if the ticket status is Success then the Success Count column should be filled as 1 as the status is Success if not I have to set to 0 .  How could I achieve this . I am new to complex SQL .

Output view should be like below . The count is 1 because ticket status is success and has previous row as VIP in Column C for the Same A column Id.

| A Id | B session Id | C customer Type | D ticket status | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | vip | Failed | 0 |
| First | B | ordinary | Success | 1 |
| First | C | ordinary | Success | 1 |
| Second | D | ordinary | Success | 0 |
| Third | E | vip | Failed | 0 |
| Third | F | ordinary | Success | 1 |

Comment: Please share sample expected output and perhaps more sample data. Also, which is the database - oracle/sql or snowflake?

Comment: Added more sample and output. I am using snowflake

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution based on count window function. Pay attention that the count is equal or larger than 1 in case there are multiple *vips* per *A ID*.

```
select t.*
      ,case when count(case "C customer Type" when 'vip' then 1 end) over (partition by "A Id" order by  "B session Id") >= 1
       and  "D ticket status" = 'Success' 
       then 1 else 0 end as E
from   t
```

| A Id | B session Id | C customer Type | D ticket status | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | vip | Failed | 0 |
| First | B | ordinary | Success | 1 |
| First | C | ordinary | Success | 1 |
| Second | D | ordinary | Success | 0 |
| Third | E | vip | Failed | 0 |
| Third | F | ordinary | Success | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=95021ec237e3d96d6dbef0882f1a0654&hide=3)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
Create View VIP_View As
Select *, Case When D.ticket_status='Success' And D.has_vip =1 Then 1 Else 0 End As E
From 
(
  Select *, MAX(Case When customer_type='vip' Then 1 Else 0 End) Over (Partition By Id) has_vip
  From datatable
) D ;
```

Or you may write it as:

```
Create View VIP_View As
Select Id, session_Id, customer_type, ticket_status, 
       Case 
         When ticket_status='Success' And MAX(Case When customer_type='vip' Then 1 Else 0 End) Over (Partition By Id) =1 
         Then 1 
         Else 0 
       End As E
From datatable;
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks to be straight-forward, using `CASE` statement for the additional column in view:

```
create or replace my_view as  
select *,
case 
    when ID in (select distinct ID from data 
                where customer_type='vip') 
                and ticket_status='Success' 
        then 1
    else 0
end col_E
 from data;
```

Comment: All the answer i tried doesnt give desired result.  Column E should be 1 only when the previous column has customer_type as VIP with same ID (A column)  and the current row has ticket status (column D ) as Success . else E should be 0 for the corresponding line and all other lines with same ID (A column)